# Problema de diretório no XAMPP

Tags: php, jquery, xampp

Meu servidor XAMPP (local host) tem os documentos de um projeto em 
**/htmdocs/projeto** , dentro tem um **index.html** que chama
Esse Código JavaScript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('#emailForm').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/email.php',
        async: true,
        data: 'email=' + $('#campoEmail').val(),
        success: function() {alert("Sucesso")}
        //beforeSend: function() { alert("Enviando")}
    });
});
```

});

HTML do formulário

```
<form id="emailForm" >
        <input id="campoEmail" class="input-center" placeholder="Digite aqui" type="email" name="email" required="true">
        </br>
        </br>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

### Minha dúvida

Qual é o diretório em que o arquivo **email.php**, deve estar dentro do XAMPP pra ser executado quando o arquivo JS chamar ?

Comment: Mostra a estrutura de diretorios do projeto, nesse caso deve ficar na raiz do projeto.

Comment: O `email.php` tem de estar na root do projeto. Provavelmente na mesma pasta do `index.html`. Já testaste isso?

Comment: Funcionou, a unica coisa estranha é que o PHP executa normal, mas o AJAX não dispara o parametro **success**

Comment: Se não entra no success é por  que ouve erro na requisição ou na resposta. use as ferramentas do navegador para inspecionar a requisição ajax feita.